# how to disable customized zoom button disabled when last zoom out in googlemap android

Tags: android, google-maps

How to disable customized button on google map in android .when I click zoom control buttons last zoom in ,I will disable that button how can I do this?

here is my code

`public void zoomOutMap(View V) {
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut();
        googleMap.animateCamera(update);
    }`

and Zoom in code here

```
    public void zoomInMap(View V) {
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn();
    googleMap.animateCamera(update);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First set camera change listener on google map.
[Link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener)

You will get a [CameraPosition](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition) object in return every time camera changes.
CameraPosition also contains zoom field in it. Check for that zoom level and disable your button according to that.